# Using "where": Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'bool'

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have entity framework code as shown below.I am getting following error in where condition.

> Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'bool' because it is not a delegate type

How to overcome this error? What is the reason for this error?

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        ClubCreation();
        List<Club> selectedClubs = GetClubs("club1");

    }

    public static void ClubCreation()
    {

        string connectionstring = "Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=NerdDinners;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30";
        using (var db = new NerdDinners(connectionstring))
        {

            Club club1 = new Club();
            club1.ClubName = "club1";

            Club club2 = new Club();
            club2.ClubName = "club2";

            Club club3 = new Club();
            club3.ClubName = "club3";

            db.Clubs.Add(club1);
            db.Clubs.Add(club2);
            db.Clubs.Add(club3);

            int recordsAffected = db.SaveChanges();


        }
    }

    public static List<Club> GetClubs(string clubName)
    {
        string connectionstring = "Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=NerdDinners;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30";
        using (var db = new NerdDinners(connectionstring))
        {

            Club club1 = new Club();
            Club club2 = new Club();
            Club club3 = new Club();


            var query = from o in db.Clubs
                        where (p => p.ClubName == "club1")
                        select o;

            return query.ToList();





        }
    }
```

Comment: What is `p` supposed to be? It seems to me like a typo of `o` which you use in your LINQ query.

Comment: And why are you hardcoding `"club1"` in your condition instead of using the `clubName` argument?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Instead of `where (p => p.ClubName == "club1")` use:

```
var query = from o in db.Clubs
            where  o.ClubName == "club1"
            select o;
```

May be you are confused with method chaining where it would be:

```
var query = db.Clubs.Where(p => p.ClubName == "club1");
```

Comment: Rather could it be... where o.ClubName == "club1"

Comment: Thanks. Suppose I am using FirstOrDefault instead of WHERE. How do we make "var query" to a Club object?

Comment: `var query = db.Clubs.FirstOrDefault(p => p.ClubName == "club1");`

Answer (score 1):

```
        var query = from o in db.Clubs
                    where o.ClubName == "club1"
                    select o;
```

Comment: LOL I was just thinking that to myself :-)

Answer (score 1):

The `=>` syntax is used in the method chain notation. You probably also want to use the `clubName` variable instead of `"club1"`.

```
var query = db.Clubs.Where (p => p.ClubName == clubName);
```

which does the same as this (which is the correct syntax for your query):

```
var query = from o in db.Clubs
            where o.ClubName == clubName
            select o;
```

Comment: You're right, but that (unlike the other answers) doesn't say what the correct syntax is.

Comment: Absolutely right. :) That would make it answered with the same answer 3 times :P

Answer (score 1):

In asp mvc Razor while i tried:

```
@if (modelItem => item.Id == 1)
 {

<span class="badge progressbar-success">Approved</span> 

 }
```

> Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'bool' because it is not a
>   delegate type

**Solution:**

```
@if (Model.FirstOrDefault().Id == 1)
{

<span class="badge progress-bar-success">Approved</span>

}
```

Hope helps someone.

Comment: @shaijt  Thank you so much It Help me a lot

Answer (score 0):

```
var query = from o in db.Clubs
            where o.ClubName == "club1"
            select o;
```

Comment: Just FYI... indenting with four spaces is meant for code blocks only. Please don't make your entire text a code block. People have edited some of your previous posts but it looks like you haven't gotten the hint. See http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help to learn how to format your posts, and please use the edit link to fix them.