# cannot convert lambda expression to type bool because it is not a delegate

Tags: c#

cannot convert lambda expression to type bool because it is not a delegate i get the following error someone help me please,

[image]

Comment: You may post your code directly instead of screenshot

Comment: It is usually preferable to paste code as text rather than an image, and highlight the locations of the errors within the code using comments.

Answer (score 7):

greater than equal to is `>=` not `=>`, that is why you are getting the error.

Comment: if anyone got this error in **asp mvc view** while using `if` condition try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34921576/2218697). Hope helps someone.

Answer (score 5):

There are several places in your code where it appears you wanted to use a comparison operator, but flipped the [operators](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6a71f45d.aspx).  Change

`=> to >=`

'=>` is the syntax C# uses to specify [lamba expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx).  So the order you write the operators is important.

**Update**

Per your comment, the variable `vastus3` is not accessible outside of the do statement block.  To resolve the error move the declaration up with the others:

`int vastus1, vastus2, vastus3;`

<strike>int</strike> `vastus3 = int.Parse(tekst1);`

Comment: Thanks alot but got 1 error more,where i would need to add vastus3 cos i get error saying the name vastus 3 does not exist in the current context,thanks alot for help so much

Comment: declare vastus3 before the do loop, it's current scoped to the do loop